# jQuery animation only working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser, jquery-animate

I have a very simple animation, were I have a tab at the side of the screen and if you click it, it will increase size. But it´s only working on IE, here is the code:

```
<script> 
$(function(){
  $("#a-tab > *").focusin(function(){
    $("#a-tab").animate({width:'320px'});
  });
  $("#a-tab > *").focusout(function(){
    $("#a-tab").animate({width:'10px'});
  });
});
</script>
```

It has to be `#a-tab > *` because of the inside content

Were is the problema, how can I make it compatible with Chrome, Firefox, etc.

Comment: you whant the full HTML file?

Comment: the page is [flores](http://claudiacabrera.cl/flores.html), just playing with the code in that page.... The side bar is the obvious google + thing :3

Comment: I have already tried with the `#("#a-tab > *").on('focusin', function() {` not working. you will see that on the link I gave you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can try sumthin like this:

```
<script> 
$(function(){
  $("#a-tab > *").focusin(function(){
    $("#a-tab").stop().animate({width:'320px'});
  });
  $("#a-tab > *").focusout(function(){
    $("#a-tab").stop().animate({width:'10px'});
  });
});
</script>
```

Just add .stop() before .animate(). I hope that works for u :)

Comment: Dam , sorry I had already resolved this, but didn't update this thread.

Comment: No problem, may be help for somebody else :)